# graphics panel in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, panel

Instead of setting image using 'background' property, I would like to draw the image using Graphics class on a panel. How can I do it in C#.Net?

Comment: What's your platform? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: Are you saying you want to paint on the panel manually instead of assigning an image to the background property?  Why would you try to re-invent the wheel?  You can set and clear the image at runtime using the background property.  I guess I don't see the benefit.  Can you explain the reasoning a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following piece of code.

```
 public class ImagePanel:Panel
{
    private Image image;

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {

            image = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Image!=null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.Image,Point.Empty);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `System.Drawing.Graphics` class to draw the things.

Details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx related to drawing

example : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Drawing_Graphics_in_C_Sharp